# Distinct column select and group by multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm attempting to group by `visitor_id` on a `page_views` table to count the "visitors" rather than "page view".

My schema consists of

```
id
visitor_id
country_code
created_at
```

The following query kind of works, but if there are multiple records in the same `minute`, then the count will be greater than 1 for that minute, but no other minutes will exist for that `visitor_id`

```sql
select DISTINCT ON (visitor_id) 
         FLOOR(EXTRACT(epoch from created_at) / 60) 
       - FLOOR(extract(epoch from now() at time zone 'utc') / 60) 
       as minutes, 
       count(DISTINCT visitor_id) as count 
from page_views 
group by visitor_id, minutes;
```

Update: 
Here is some sample data and expected results

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | visitor_id | created_at  |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 |          1 | 1571520145  |
|  2 |          1 |  1571520085 |
|  3 |          3 |  1571520085 |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

This would basically return 1 count for each different minute, so it would effectively only count each unique visitor, regardless of the "minute"

Comment: You have said what you don't want to do, but not what you do want to do.  How can "count(DISTINCT visitor_id)" ever be greater than one, if you group by visitor_id?

Comment: @jjanes I basically want to count each unique visitor, rather than page views.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  If you want to count unique visitors, what is `minutes` doing in the query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the question with some sample data and a better explanation. I want to basically group the first instance of the `visitor_id` with the `minutes`, so there would only be one `visitor_id` returned. Basically when the visitor first visited the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm attempting to group by visitor_id on a page_views table to count the "visitors" rather than "page view".

I am going to interpret this as wanting the unique visitors during certain time periods.  That is not exactly what this says, but it is more consistent with the query.

If so, `visitor_id` does not belong in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select (FLOOR(EXTRACT(epoch from created_at) / 60) -
        FLOOR(extract(epoch from now() at time zone 'utc') / 60) 
       ) as minutes, 
       count(DISTINCT visitor_id) as count 
from page_views 
group by minutes
order by minutes;
```

If you want to count only the first time that someone visits, use a subquery:

```
select (FLOOR(EXTRACT(epoch from created_at) / 60) -
        FLOOR(extract(epoch from now() at time zone 'utc') / 60) 
       ) as minutes, 
       count(DISTINCT visitor_id) as count 
from (select visitor_id, min(created_at as created_at
      from page_views 
      group by visitor_id
     ) v
group by minutes
order by minutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm attempting to group by visitor_id on a page_views table to count the "visitors"

If you want to group by visitors, then `GROUP BY visitor_id` is what you want.  The question then becomes what you're counting for each visitor. If you want to count how many times each visitor appears in the data, `count(*)` will do that.  `count(distinct visitor_id)` is unnecessary; we're already grouping by visitor.

You seem to want to know something about minutes per visitor, too.  Whatever it is, it's some kind of aggregation, perhaps `sum()`.  If so, your query could be simplified to standard SQL in the form:

```
select 
     visitor_id, 
     sum(  FLOOR(EXTRACT(epoch from created_at) / 60) 
         - FLOOR(extract(epoch from now() at time zone 'utc') / 60) ) 
     as minutes, 
     count(*) as count 
from page_views 
group by visitor_id
```

The general rule for `group by` is that everything in the SELECT that isn't in the GROUP BY must be an aggregation. Another way to think about it is that anything in the select that isn't grouped by is a function of the values for that group.